# mvc4 validation numbers throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a field in my model that I want it to be just numbers

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Cheque ID is required")]
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9])*", ErrorMessage = "Cheque ID must be numbers only.")]
[Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999", ErrorMessage = "Cheque ID must be a number between {1} and {999}.")]
```

I tried this:

and in my view I used this

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.chequeID, new {placeholder = "Enter The Location", @Value = "" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chequeID)
</div>
```

But I go this exception

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here :

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999", ErrorMessage = "Cheque ID must be a number between {1} and {999}.")]
```

This index `{999}` is out of range. Like a `string.Format`, if you have, for example, 3 parameters, your string should include them as `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, following the specified order.

In your case, replacing `{999}` by `{2}` will display "9999" as the maximum value (`{0}` is the property name, that is why min value is `{1}`).